# Divs not showing when uploaded to server

Tags: css, css-position

2 Divs are not showing when I upload to a server, but they show ok on my localhost(wampp).
Can anyone offer assistance on why this may be?
The divss in question are'footer' and 'poster'

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <?php include '../inc/header.php';?>
    <div id="info">
       <div id="what">
           <span class="h1">WHAT IS IT?</span>
        </div>
        <?php 
           include '../inc/connect.php';
       $data = mysql_query("SELECT info FROM mainhomepagecontent")
           or die(mysql_error());          
           while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
          echo "<span class='text'>";
      echo nl2br($info['info']);
          echo "</span>";
            } 
         ?> 
      </div>         
  <?php include '../inc/poster.php';?>
  <?php include '../inc/footer.php';?>
   </div>
```

footer file

```
<?php
$output = "<div class='footer'>";
$output .= "<div class='wsd'>";
$output .= "Site Developed by Webslinger Development";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "<div class='ngcopyright'>";
$output .= "All Rights Reserved 2013 &copy Needle Gangsta's ";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "</div>";
echo $output;
?>
```

poster file

```
<?php
$output ='<div class="poster">';
$output .='<div class="posterfixed">';
$output .='<div class="eighteenlogo">';
$output .= '<img src="../images/siteimages/18logo.png" />';
$output .= '</div>';
$output .='<div id="wherewhen">';
$output .='<div id="when">';
$output .='<span class="h2">WHEN IS IT?</span><br /> <span class="text2">9TH/10TH            
FEBUARY 2014</span>';
$output .='</div>';
$output .='<div id="where">';
$output .='<span class="h2">WHERE IS IT?</span><br /> <span class="text2">Holiday Inn 
(EAST)<br />
London Rd<br />
Newport Pagnell<br />
Milton Keynes<br /> MK16 0JA</span>';
$output .='</div>';
$output .='</div>';
$output .='</div>';
echo $output;
?>
```

and the css

```
.header{
float:left;
margin:15px 0 0 0;
width:280px;
min-height:382px;
}

.headerfixed{
position:fixed;
width:280px;
min-height:382px;
background-image:url(../images/siteimages/logo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.wrapper{
width:1280px;
position:relative;
border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
background:#000000;
overflow:hidden;
}

/*sets the left side div*/
.poster{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
right:0;
width:390px;
min-height:512px;
}

.posterfixed{
position:fixed;
width:390px;
min-height:512px;
background-image:url(../images/siteimages/background.png);
}

.eighteenlogo{
position:absolute;
right:10px;
top:450px;
}



/*sets the footer*/
.footer{
float:left;
min-width:1280px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thanks for looking.................

Comment: Are you sure your paths to your css are correct?

Comment: Yes, like I say, it works on localhost ok. On the server if i move the footer and poster includes to below the header include they appear bu everything else goes missing!..............

Comment: Could be that they are all using the $output variable....cant see that being the reason....but just try using different variables for each file.  Stupid suggestion, but hey....who knows

Comment: I give that a try, but alas it didnt work.................

Comment: Ok heres where i am now. if i take the <div class="info"></div> out the the poster div shows! I havent a clue what is happening!

Comment: What happens if you don't echo any of it...and just build it like normal.  So instead of using php to echo, just build it like a regular html page, still save it as a php, and still include....do you know what i mean?

Comment: I tried that too, the same happens!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Heardoc](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)) instead of concatenating strings. I think it is easier to see the indentation and it can help you spot unclosed tags:

```
$output = <<<EOF
<div class="footer">
  <div class="wsd">
    Site Developed by Webslinger Development
  </div>
  <div class="ngcopyright">
   All Rights Reserved 2013 &copy; Needle Gangsta's
  </div>
</div>
EOF;

echo $output;
```

Anything within the `EOF` identifier (This can be anything you want, see the reference.) will NOT ignore any whitespace.